# Function for checking if dictionary values contains 2 parameters

Tags: python, pandas

I want to write a function that is checking if 2 values are satisfied, then perform finding the highest value for the third parameter. For example:

`myFunction(condition1, condition2, parameter)`

My data is in a dictionary (can put it `Data Frame`, don't know what is the best approach. Guess it is dictionary of dictionaries right now). `condition1` and `condition2` has more than 1 values, e.g.,

condition1 looks like: `{0: ['pizza', 'pasta', 'salad'], 1: ['kebab', 'pasta', 'stew'],...}`
condition2 looks like: `{0: ['italian'], 1: ['american','mexican', 'italian'],...}`
parameter (rating) looks like: `{0:67, 1:56, 2:32,...}`, and
name looks like: `{0:'macys',1:'maze',2:'mcdonalds'...}`

Basically, I want to find the best restaurant who serves `'pizza'` and it is `'italian'`, and has the highest `'rating'` (return the name of the restaurant).

Only thing I can get is to show me all the keys that contain​ `'pizza'` with this code:

```
[key for key, value in datadict["condition1"].items() if 'pizza' in value]
```

but when adding `and` for the second condition:

```
def myfunction(condition1, condition2, highest):
    [key for key, value in datadict["condition1"].items() if condition1 in value] and [key for key, value in datadict["condition2"].items() if condition2 in value]
```

I get some weird results. Also, I tried with this and it's getting results but based for only one condition:

```
def func(condition1):
    for i in datadict["condition1"]: #reaching the keys of dict
        for x in datadict["condition1"][i]: #reaching every element in tuples
            if x==condition1: #if match found..
                print ("{} holding {}.".format(i,x)) #printing it..
funct('pizza')
```

Output:

```
8 holding pizza.
30 holding pizza.
33 holding pizza.
```

But with:

```
def func(condition1, condition2):
        for i in datadict["condition1"], j in datadict["condition2"]: #reaching the keys of dict
            for x in datadict["condition1"][i] and y in datadict["condition2"][j]: #reaching every element in tuples
                if x==condition1 and y==condition2: #if match found..
                    print ("{} holding {}.".format(i,x)) #printing it..
    funct('pizza', 'italian')
```

I get:

> NameError: name 'j' is not defined

how to properly check for other condition and return name instead of the key?

Comment: Are the keys always consecutive numbers? You appear to have *lists* instead, with the indices moved to dictionary keys.

Comment: how can i check this? I pulled data from REST API with "requests", for condition1 is: 'condition1': list(y['cuisine']['name'] for y in get_restaurant_json["cuisine"])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to invert your data sets. You have ids pointing to attributes, but are searching for attributes to point you to ids.

Build [sets](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set) from your conditions, so you can intersect these:

```
cuisine_to_id = {}
for id, cuisines in condition1.items():
    for c in cuisines:
        cuisine_to_id.setdefault(c, set()).add(id)

style_to_id = {}
for id, styles in condition2.items():
    for s in styles:
         style_to_id.setdefault(s, set()).add(id)
```

So now you have dictionaries that have keys like `'pizza'` point to a set of ids (`{0, 2, ...}`). You want to do this **once**, after initially loading this data, there is no need to repeatedly build these sets.

If you were building the `condition1` and `condition2` dictionaries from another dataset of restaurants, just build the above name-to-set-of-ids mappings instead. The `condition*` dictionaries are not all that useful for anything else.

Picking out matching restaurants is then a set operation, `&` gives us an intersection for restaurants that match both conditions:

```
matches = cuisine_to_id['pizza'] & style_to_id['italian']
```

then find the restaurant id from the matched ids with the highest rating, and map that one id to a name:

```
return names[max(matches, key=parameter.get)]
```

This, incidentally, is the kinds of operations that *relational databases* are absolutely great at. You want to put this information into a SQL database; Python includes the embedded [`sqlite3` database library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html), no need to set up a separate server here.

You could then run queries like

```
SELECT r.name
FROM restaurants r
INNER JOIN restaurant_cuisines rc ON rc.restaurant_id = r.id
INNER JOIN cuisines c ON rc.cuisine_id = c.id
INNER JOIN restaurant_styles rs ON rs.restaurant_id = r.id
INNER JOIN styles s ON rs.style_id = s.id
WHERE c.name = 'pizza' AND s.name = 'italian'
ORDER BY r.rating DESC
LIMIT 1
```

That may look a little daunting, but it'll be *really really fast and efficient*.

Comment: it throws: AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'set_default' while executing for id, conds in condition1.items()

Comment: @Mr.Mister. Sorry, my mistake, that was a typo. Remove the underscores.

Comment: tnx, what will happen in case they have same rating, it will take just first or all?

Comment: @Mr.Mister. It’ll take just one.

Comment: @Mr.Mister. If you need a list of matching restaurants with the highest rating (which could be a list of one), then first get the maximum rating with `max_rating = max(parameter[id] for id in matches)` then all restaurant names with that rating: `return [names[id] for id in matches if parameter[id] == max_rating]`.

Comment: thank you very much, last question I promise :) . How can i add this "parameter" into function if I have more then 1 parameter (rating, distance, number_of_tables etc), so I can choose which one I want, e.g. myfunction('pizza', 'italian', 'distance')? tnx and sorry if i bother you :(

Comment: Or how to search for all restaurants based on condition1 for example (myfunction('all', 'italian', 'rating')

Comment: @Mr.Mister. so build dictionaries of sets for each aspect. Instead of creating separate `cuisine_to_id`, `style_to_id`, etc dictionaries, create on `aspects` dictionary with `cuisine`, `style`, etc. keys each pointing to such a name-to-set-of-ids dictionaries. Then you can dynamically create an intersection of the sets based on your criteria.

Comment: `def myfunction(**criteria):` would accept keyword arguments, then looping over `criteria.items()` lets you pick sets to intersect together; `matches = set.intersection(*(aspects[aspect][value] for name, value in criteria.items()))`.

Comment: still not getting how to grab all conditions with 'all' parameter in function... sorry :/

Comment: @Mr.Mister.: you'd have ta ask a follow-up question then, as this is rapidly getting too broad for comments.

Answer (score 0):

You could find keys of food1 and food2 that match your conditions using list comprehension and then return name of restaurant that has highest value in `rating`.

```
food1 = {0: ['pizza', 'pasta', 'salad'], 1: ['kebab', 'pasta', 'stew'], 2:['sushi', 'pizza']}
food2 = {0: ['italian'], 1: ['american','mexican', 'italian'], 2: ['polish', 'italian']}
rating = {0:67, 1:56, 2:32}
names = {0:'macys',1:'maze',2:'mcdonalds'}

def myFunction(condition1, condition2):
    filtered = [k for k, v in food1.items() if condition1 in v and condition2 in food2[k]]

    if not filtered:
        return

    return names[max(filtered, key=rating.get)]

print(myFunction('pizza', 'italian'))
```